# Optimal/Best Algorithm to look for a sentence in huge text

Tags: java, string, algorithm, text

Suppose we have a text size of (1 GB) and let's assume the following text as a sample:

> Stack Overflow is a privately held website, the flagship site of the Stack Exchange Network, created in 2008 by Jeff Atwood and Joel Spolsky. It was created to be a more open alternative to earlier Q&A sites such as Experts-Exchange.

As an input search string of **Iwc** I'm expecting the following result : **It was created ** .

In the sentence :
**First word begins with I** ,
**Second word begins with w** and
**Third word begins with c** to give me that result

Algorithm should get the result as quickly as possible.

Comment: This is way too broad. It might be more suited for [programmers.se].

Comment: @GeraldSchneider how is that broad? It asks for a specific algorithm to solve that problem of word search by first character in a big text.

Comment: Not an answer, but just a thought. I would first "extract" (or name that operation "index" or anything) based on your rule. That is, transform a text "This is a text" to the string "TIAT", and eventually store it in the db, then just do an string.indexOf("IA") on that field (or any db-related function that can be used there). You could use triggers to implement the extra field update to keep it in sync...

Comment: the phase you are looking for should be in one sentence? `siw` -> `Spolsky. It was` is this allowed?

Comment: can't you load the file into the memory (~1GB), compress the text by keeping only the first letter(~1GB/4 (avg word length) = 250MB) (also saving a reference to the full word) and apply standard text-searching algorithm (e.g. Knuth-Morris-Pratt) to the compressed text?

Comment: @svs good question , no problem with symbols we can escape them , so yes this is allowed .

Comment: If you search multiple times the **fastest way** would be to build a (big) HashMap once (complexity: O(numberOfSearchedWords)). Is memory (RAM) a limiting factor? If yes than a slow O(numberOfCharactersInText) algorithm is the "best".

Comment: @GeraldSchneider: Programmers is not a site for "way too broad" questions. If it's too broad here, it's too broad there.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut: It's too broad because this is not a "find me the algorithm" site. If Ahmad has a specific problem with an actual implementation attempt then we can help to resolve it.

Comment: @PreferenceBean so 90% of the questions under the algorithm tag are too broad? this is becoming ridiculous.

Comment: Would you prefer an algorithm that optimizes time complexity or memory complexity? What if any are the limitations?

Comment: @Qbyte I like the HashMap idea for performance but a HashMap doesn't guarantee any order (which is key to the requirements) so how would you solve for that? By dropping the remaining text into a sorted List? Something like HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>?

Comment: @Assaf Time complexity .

Comment: @DanK I thought of something like this: `HashMap<char, HashMap<char, HashMap<char, HashMap<char, HashMap<char, int>>>>>` which maps almost all word combinations in a text of this size and is in worst case about 1.5 GB in size. The resulting index is than associated to an Array where all words are saved.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut: Yes, and I couldn't agree more. If only more people understood what this site is not for.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut I frequent [algorithm] for almost 2 years now. Most questions are much more detailled than this. It doesn't even mention whether OP needs a "one-off" approach with one query or an indexing approach with preprocessing and multiple queries

Comment: [Rolling Hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_hash) can find a substring within a string in linear time - perhaps consider this approach if you want a *fast* and *in place* solution

Answer (score 6):

You ask for the "best" algorithm. I can think of the following definitions of "best":

1. fastest to implement
2. fastest to run once (lowest run-time) given enough memory
3. lowest memory footprint
4. fastest to run for large numbers of queries, so that each additional query requires minimal time
5. a compromise between one or more of the above

Each has a different solution. For example, solving for **2)** or **3)**, you can't beat writing a small state machine that reads through the input word by work, keeping track of how far it is along finding a full match. Complexity would be O(totalWordCount)

Solving for **4)** is more interesting - you would have to build an efficient index and look things up in that index. A depth-limited [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) structure would then be optimal, since complexity would be O(queryWordCount), which is << O(totalWordCount). However, building the index is expensive (although linear in O(totalWordCount) for a fixed depth), and would make this a bad approach for **2)**.

Finally, the folks at https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/ will tell you about the joy of minimizing **6)** the amount of characters in your code.

---

Expanding on a Trie-based solution:

- First build an a trie. Store word initials as node labels, and an `ArrayList<Integer>` associated with each node with offsets to where the words with those initial-sequences can be found within the text. To keep index-size and build-time in check, you will need to limit the trie to a given depth (a depth-5 trie would only allow you to find sequences of initials of length 5 or shorter). With a maximal depth of 5, I estimate that the index size will be similar to your text - so make sure to have plenty of RAM available.
- Searching is just a matter of walking trie nodes, starting from the root, until you either do not find the next node you need (initials in that order do not appear in text) or you have walked to the end of your initials. In the second case, the contents of the arraylist are the offsets to the text where the initialed words can be found, in their correct order.

Comment: Trie is not really the correct data structure because you would need to insert all k-grams for k <= m where m is the maximum query size. If m = Omega(n) this is quadratic time + space. You probably want some kind of suffix automaton or suffix tree/array, all of which can be built in linear time. Suffix arrays can also be compressed very well, so the index would probably be much smaller than text and still support optimal query time.

Comment: "Suffix trees are a special kind of tries, and suffer the same limitations regarding size." Now that statement is just incorrect. You can build a suffix tree in linear time, it takes linear space, it represents *all suffixes* of the string and allows you to find patterns in linear time in the length of the pattern. So is strictly superior to what you describe, *and* takes less space

Comment: @NiklasB. By golly, you're right. Removing my wrong comment - I had not looked Suffix Trees up properly, and was instead going by the short quote in the [wikipedia Trie entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Trie&action=edit&section=7) that said that Suffix Trees were a specialized version.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know anything about algorithms, but for a simple solution I'd use a StringTokenizer, delimited with a space, and if the stringTokenizer.nextToken() returns a string starting with the letter you're looking for, check the result of the next stringTokenizer.nextToken() call, and so on

Comment: actually OP doesn't search a simple solution but best one....